# gdalwarp to EPSG 3857 of a Bing tile

Tags: coordinate-system

I'm quite new to GDAL and to remote sensing.

What I would like to do is to assign from scratch the EPSG 3857 System Of Reference to a Bing tile (a not georeferenced jpg) downloaded from the Bing server.

I've already computed the coordinates [x, y] this tile should have in the 3857 SoR and create a world file from them, but how can I now project my tile to 3857 by using this .tfw?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have the tfw calculated thats 90% of your work done. You should simply rename tfw to jgw (which is what its supposed to be called when its put together with jpg file), and the software should be able to recognize it.

Theres no need for further reprojection because bing i think also uses spherical mercator projection, which is also known as google projection (hence the other EPSG code for it: 900913) or as you know it, under EPSG: 3857